# Installing Ubuntu 18.04 from DVD

Tags: dual-boot

I have downloaded Ubuntu 18.04 to a DVD, but my Dell Inspiron running Win 10 doesn't tell me how to boot from the DVD.  I no longer get a list of bootable drives to select from.

Answer (score 0):

You need to change the boot order in your motherboard's BIOS settings in order to boot from your optical media drive containing the Ubuntu disc.

This is not actually a feature of Ubuntu, but part of your motherboard's firmware (BIOS).  Interfaces for BIOS are not consistent in the industry, even among hardware from the same manufacturer, so you may need to consult the manual that came with your computer to find out the exact process for your system.

Generally, a splash screen will display briefly when you first power on your computer that will indicate which key to hold down during boot to enter "setup" or "options".  The key is often: `ESC`, `DEL`, or a function key like `F1`, `F2`, `F11`, or `F12`, etc.

Once you have gotten into the BIOS menu, you will need to elevate your optical drive's boot priority above all other bootable drives -- again this process is not consistent between devices so you may need to consult with the documentation from the hardware (motherboard) manufacturer.

Comment: You need to bring up the BIOS **Boot menu** by repeatedly tapping the F12 key as soon as you power up the computer. When the menu appears, under 'Legacy Boot' you should see your DVD ROM listed. Select it and make sure your DVD is in the drive, then press 'Enter'.

Comment: @PaulBenson: This may be true of Dell (I am not certain) but not all manufacturers use `F12`.

Comment: OP stated his machine is a Dell Inspiron.

Comment: Someone else had proposed an edit to change the answer to only say F12.  Since this is a forum for Ubuntu--and not Dell, I think it's important that the answer is not machine specific, but it does help in the comments.  Considering how the process to enter BIOS is not even consistent between devices from the same manufacturer, I would not be surprised if this doesn't work for all Dell machines either.