# Stuck on boot after I upgraded to Ubuntu 18.04 from 16.04. Nvidia Jetson TX2

Tags: 18.04, nvidia

I have an Nvidia Jetson TX2 developer machine. I have never used Ubuntu before however when I booted the machine from new it loaded up fine and prompted me to update to Ubuntu 18.04 which I did.
At various points it asked if I wanted to replace files, which I agreed to as I haven't done any work on it yet so figure nothing would be lost.
Eventually it said it needed to restart which I did, all looked good as the various commands streamed down the screen, however when it got to:

```
[19.823105] such-tegra 3440000.sdhci: Tuning already done, restoring the best tap value: 21
```

It just hangs there.

How do I fix this so I can get into the machine?

I upgraded from 16.04

Comment: Please [edit] your question to indicate what you updated to 18.04 from

Comment: @24601 to be honest with you I don't know what it updated from, the machine came with a preinstalled version, which was a few years old. I'm going through the docs now to see if I can find the version

Comment: I suspect it is an old now unsupported version which you cannot upgrade to. Maybe best to cut your losses and consider a vanilla installation to a currently supported LTS version 18.04 or 20.04 so you are working from a known base.

Comment: I don't know how to do this, I think I may have bricked it now I can't get into recovery mode or use the terminal

Comment: [Install Ubuntu from CD](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1039608/installing-ubuntu-18-04-from-dvd#1039628)

Comment: It is a Nvidia Jetson TX2 which is a developer kit to test AI models, it has no cd drive I have created a bootable usb but I can't get it to boot from that. To get into recovery mode there is a hardware button to hold down when powering on, when I do this it lights up as if it's on but the screen is blank.

Comment: have you researched [boot from USB](https://www.ionos.com/digitalguide/server/tools/how-do-i-install-ubuntu-from-a-usb-drive/)

Comment: Yeah I have gone through all the forums on Nvidia and a bunch of other places. What the process should be is you hold the recovery button, then hit the power button wait for a few seconds and release the recovery button which then takes you to a boot menu where to can choose to boot from the usb. But I never get the recovery mode menu

Comment: That's about the limit of my knowledge on this, Sorry.

Comment: No problem thanks for your help